# Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angularfire2

I have this error when i get object from database with parameters :

[image]

code component:

```
 constructor(public employeeService:EmployeeService, public router:Router, public activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.email = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['email'];
        this.employeeService.getEmployee(this.email).subscribe(employee => {
            if (employee.salary >0) { this.hasSalary = true;}
            this.employee = employee;
            console.log(this.employee);
        });
      }
```

code service:

```
   getEmployee(email:string)
   {
     return this.item = this.af.object('employeesdb/'+email).valueChanges() as FirebaseObjectObservable<Employee>; 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the collection with the given email and get the object. Try

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.email = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['email'];
    this.employeeService.getEmployee(this.email).subscribe(employee => {
        employee.forEach(snapshot=>{
            console.log(snapshot);
        }
    });
  }
```

Use angularfire's query method

```
getEmployee(email:string)
   {
     return this.item = this.af.list('/employeesdb', ref => ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo(email)).valueChanges(); 
   }
```

Comment: i forgot to add a slash in the beginning of path, i updated in answer, try now.

Comment: and you probably don't need `as FirebaseObjectObservable<Employee>`

Comment: also error Hareesh .. I get parameters but error in path database .. in my case path is :namedb concatenate with email : namedbemail .. how to get data form firebase with email and I use angularfire2

Comment: you should consider renaming your database names. If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127. check this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree) for more

Answer (score 0):

Like the errors says, your path may not contain dots (.)
You are using an email address as parameter which obviously contains a dot. 
I'd recommend generating an ID for each employee and getting the employee by the assigned ID.

Comment: but in database firebase i have this output :https://imgur.com/a/Es2DI .. and this is attributs: lastname , firstname,email,phone,salary and country

Comment: any help pleaseee